# Firebase Database until authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to migrate my SQLite database to a Firebase DB, and i have never used before a NoSQL DB so i'm having a lot of troubles.

I want every user to have their own "database" so what i have done until now is saving the data with this:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

but the problem is that if I authenticate a user as anonymous to save it correctly, when the users authenticates with Google the Uid changes.

So what should I do to fix this? 
I have read every doc from the [Firebase page](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/) and i don't know what to do

To manage the log in i'm using FirebaseUI:

```
Integer resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    // not signed in
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setProviders(
                            AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                            AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                    .setTheme(R.style.IndigoTheme)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
} else {
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, getActivity(), 0);
    if (dialog != null) {
        //This dialog will help the user update to the latest GooglePlayServices
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That seems like the wrong site to be working from, since it's for the 2.x SDK and you're using the latest version. You're looking for the [documentation on upgrading an anonymous account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen oh thank you! I just read it but i'm using FirebaseUI to manage the log in so i don't really know how to use this, i'm editing my question to show my login code

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you should follow the Standard Procedure of letting user Browse around your app anonymously and then ask them to login either by Google,Facebook or through Sign Up/Sign In or any other way you prefer.